# Social Media Buttons in PHP, HTML: Taking too much time to load and distorting page

Tags: php, html, button, media

I've added social media buttons on my sidebar using PHP and HTML syntax. However everytime I refresh the page, it takes 4-5 secs to load and during the last second it distorts all the context of the page, then it becomes normal and looks exactly the way I want it.

Is there a way to remove this time-lag and distortion of page?

Here is the code:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

And I've put this part of the code inside the body.

```
<div> <g:plusone></g:plusone> </div></br>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" data-via="YourSite">Tweet</a>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://ph.one.un.org/omt" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="800" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div></br></br></br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and make it so you only have one request. I generally use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) for that kind of thing. It's pretty nifty.